# Freemarker - compose language switch url

Tags: spring, url, freemarker

I am using freemarker template engine with Spring and I want to add or replace `lang=xxx` parameter in the href attribute of link element when rendering page.

The closest solution I have found is following:

```
<a href="${springMacroRequestContext.getRequestUri()}?lang=en'/>English</a>
```

But this is not sufficient when I have URL with parameters and fragments because I will miss them. For example `http://localhost/sports/search?query=Volleyball&lang=cs#some-fragment` results in `http://localhost/sports/search?lang=en`

How to compose the URL with added or changed `lang` parameter in freemarker and do not miss any part of requested URL?

Comment: did yuo try to compose the URL parameters server side and then pass the final string to the template?

Comment: I thought that it would be possible to access whole URL from the freemarker. Ok, so I would create the link and add it in the spring model or provide custom bean with method to compose the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preferred to do it in Java, this simple implementation does not take into account hashes (`#`) or the presence of the given parameter in the url..

```
public static String addParamToUrl(String url, String paramName, String paramValue){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(url);
    //adding separator
    if(url.indexOf('?') == -1){
        buffer.append('?');
    }else if(!url.endsWith("?") && !url.endsWith("&")){
        buffer.append('&');
    }        

    buffer.append(paramName);
    if(paramValue != null){
        buffer.append("=");
        buffer.append(URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8"));
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Put this method in a Class (i.e:`Utils.java`) that can be staticly accessed by Freemarker engine and than:

```
<#assign url = Utils.addParamToUrl(springMacroRequestContext.getRequestUri(), "lang", "en") />

<a href="${url}">English</a>
```

To expose your `Utils` class you have to customize `FreemarkerManager`

```
public class MyFreemarkerManager extends FreemarkerManager {

    public MyFreemarkerManager(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateContext(ScopesHashModel model, ValueStack stack, Object action, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super.populateContext(model, stack, action, request, response);

        try {

            BeansWrapper beansWrapper = new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_24).build();
            TemplateHashModel staticModels = beansWrapper.getStaticModels();

            TemplateHashModel utils = (TemplateHashModel)staticModels.get("com.package.Utils");
            model.put("Utils", utils);  

        } catch (TemplateModelException e) {
            //...
        }       

    }
}
```

Finally you have to tell Spring you are using `MyFreemarkerManager` as manager for Freemarker.